# how to change image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change an image after running a jquery function? I have an slideToggle function connected to the click of a div element containing the text and the image of an arrow, which I want to change into a different image when clicked.

HTML

```
<div id="italia">
    CONCESSIONI NAZIONALI<img id="freccia" src="freccia_su.jpg"  >
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#nazione").click(function(){
    $(".estero").slideToggle("slow", function() { 
        
     });
});
```

I tried adding this statement, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#freccia').attr('src','freccia_giu.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of changing the image using links.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#Change", function() {
  $("#freccia").attr("src", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEUPo5FVBSiJTygFAL273wRmA0DGMI1NGnku9ghDnNEf6w5MRLGk03_i51lWqhnwe1SWU&usqp=CAU");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="italia">
  <img id="freccia" src="https://cdn.42matters.com/sdk/developers.google.com.png">
</div>

<button type="button" id="Change">Change image</button>
```

In your case you should add `/` to the beggining of your path in `$('#freccia').attr('src','freccia_giu.jpg');`
so it should look like this `$('#freccia').attr('src','/freccia_giu.jpg');`

It depends on where the image is saved inside your project.
If it's inside the root folder then `'freccia_giu.jpg'` should work just fine, but incase it's inside some other directory you need to define the path to the image. For example `'/images/freccia_giu.jpg'`

---

### Edit:

---

If you want to alternate between the images you can do this :

```js
var clickCount = 0;
$(document).on("click", "#Change", function() {
  if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
    $("#freccia").attr("src", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEUPo5FVBSiJTygFAL273wRmA0DGMI1NGnku9ghDnNEf6w5MRLGk03_i51lWqhnwe1SWU&usqp=CAU");
  } else {
    $("#freccia").attr("src", "https://cdn.42matters.com/sdk/developers.google.com.png");
  }
  clickCount++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="italia">
  <img id="freccia" src="https://cdn.42matters.com/sdk/developers.google.com.png">
</div>

<button type="button" id="Change">Change image</button>
```

Comment: almost perfect only that in this way the image changes only once instead it should change every time with its opposite or if the slide is closed there must be a down arrow otherwise an up one

Comment: @LorenzoDonadio you can add 2 buttons or alternate between the 2 paths using an `if()` statement to see which path is currently used. Or you can have a click counter and see `if(count%2 ==0) { image1 }else{ image2 }`

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you put the expression `$("#freccia").attr("src",<newurl>);` in the right place:

```js
let i=0;
$("#nazione").click(function(){
  $(".estero").slideToggle("slow", function() {  }); 
  $("#freccia").attr("src",`https://picsum.photos/id/${++i}/300/200`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="italia">
CONCESSIONI NAZIONALI<img id="freccia" src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/300/200">
</div>
<button id="nazione">next image</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).on("click", "#italia", function() {
  if ($("#freccia").attr("src") == ("file://devil/backup_dipendenti/DEV_CONTOGIOCO/clienti/freccia_su.jpg")) {
    $("#freccia").attr("src","freccia_giu.jpg");
  } else {
    $("#freccia").attr("src","freccia_su.jpg");
  }
});
```

Comment: It's better if you use a counter or .contains rather than compare with the full path because if you change the images path later you would have to come change the code again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.